# Canvas line edges not smooth. How to fix this?

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

I am searching a radial progress bar. recently found in stackoverflow using canvas. but the circle not smooth edges. how to fix this blurry image.

```
JSFIDDLE : http://jsfiddle.net/fd3k7prh/
```

Image:
[image]

Comment: That's called antialiasing... if you zoom in, you'll get blurriness. Don't zoom in.

Comment: Are you sure your browser's zoom is at 100%? Everything looks fine here, but when i zoom in a tiny bit the lines do get blurry. Try pressing cmd+0 or ctrl+0 to reset your zoom.

Comment: No, Usually its not look like normal shape.

Comment: Use SVG, if possible instead of canvas. SVG is vector based, scales very well, while CANVAS renders bitmap, which does not scale up lossless.

Answer (score 0):

It seems OK on my screen. As long as you don't scale canvas inside e.g. CSS it should not be blurred. Please make sure whether you have zoom enabled in your browser (e.g. by holding ctrl+mouse scroll) and your browser is displaying 100% image.

As Canvas is displaying vector image, it should not be blurred in normal zoom. However, zooming it in will always make it blurry, because it needs to be overscaled.